# vector equations - boat crossing river

Tags: vectors

[image: Question]

Looking at the question above, it is asking to find the speed that the boat will have with respect to a stationary observer on the bank of the canal.

I have set up a vector diagram using the given vectors, and the answer that I am getting is through using the cosine rule.

So what I get is:

> $$\sqrt(5.67^2+2.76^2 - 2*cos(60)*2.76*5.67)=$$ 
>   resultant speed
>   But, the answer you get is incorrect. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this suppose we sail at an angle $\theta$ w.r.t. ground but we want to sail at an angle 60-degree w.r.t. river

thus $$\tan(60)=\frac{v\sin(\theta)}{v\cos(\theta)+v_c}$$
$$\frac{v\sin(\theta)}{v\cos(\theta)+v_c}=\sqrt3$$
$$\frac{5.67\sin(\theta)}{5.67\cos(\theta)+2.76}=\sqrt3$$
(in picture I have written it $-v_c$ by mistake it should be $+v_c$
[image]